# Windows Audio playback agent update title and artist live

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, background-audio

How could i update the windows audio playback agent properties like title and artist, live ,when it is playing. I want to update the title every 20 seconds without stopping the music which is playing? please help. I tried this but its stopping and replaying at every 20 seconds which is annoying. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace PhoneApp2
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        string Artist;
        string Song;
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
            timer.Start();
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.IfModifiedSince] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://air-online2.hitfm.md/status_hitfm.xsl"));
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += client_DownloadStringCompleted;
        }

        void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] FullTitle = e.Result.Substring(166).Split('-');
            Artist= FullTitle[0];

            if(Artist.Contains(":"))
            {
               Artist=FullTitle[0].Replace(":",string.Empty);
            }
            Song = FullTitle[1].Replace(" ", string.Empty);
            if (BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState != PlayState.Playing)
            {
                BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://air-online2.hitfm.md/hitfm.mp3"), Artist, Song, null, null);
                BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();
            }
            else
            {
                BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track = new AudioTrack(new Uri("http://air-online2.hitfm.md/hitfm.mp3"), Artist, Song, null, null);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what? nobody can't help me? lol

Comment: Did you try to edit the track itself using BeginEdit and EndEdit?

Comment: oh yes, i tried doing that, but it gave an error , wich was something like : InvalidOperation. i startetd like that:
    track.BeginEdit();
    track.Title="some title";
    track.Artist="Some Artist";
    track.EndEdit();